# ArcGIS pro Runtime Error: Cannot open shape file through Python Add-In

Tags: arcpy, dem, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool

I am facing runtime error while running this [Python script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sJxrQZpXHaNYT5hQG6klHdKS0-Hxl6k9/view?usp=sharing) as an extension to ArcGIS Pro version 2.522081

I also checked for minor errors and typos in the script, have gone through the documentation of ESRI, and tried debugging the script but still facing the same error. The main problem is this loop maybe because of cursor but I am not sure.

```
def get_unique_point(line_layer,start_of_drainages):
global start_of_drainages_fullpath
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(workspace ,start_of_drainages,"Multipoint","","DISABLED","DISABLED",line_layer)
geometries = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(line_layer,arcpy.Geometry())
#arcpy.AddMessage("-"*22)
startlist =[]
lastlist =[]
for geometry in geometries:
    startlist.append([round(geometry.firstPoint.X, 2),round(geometry.firstPoint.Y, 2)])
    lastlist.append([round(geometry.lastPoint.X, 2),round(geometry.lastPoint.Y, 2)])

unique_list=[]
for x in startlist:
    if x not in lastlist:
        unique_list.append(x)

for zz in unique_list:
    array = arcpy.Array(arcpy.Point(zz[0], zz[1]))
    Multipoint = arcpy.Multipoint(array)
    cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(start_of_drainages_fullpath,["SHAPE@"])
    cursor.insertRow([Multipoint])
    del cursor
```

I am using the DEM raster file source from USGS and a drainage network feature as my input. I have attached [my package](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6693f50962ea456783e6587722b66526). You can access the input data files from here.

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You are not describing the problem you are trying to solve which is needed in order to understand your code. What are you trying to insert, what is `unique_list` etc.?

Comment: I cannot find what this error means or what could be causing it? I Included the function of unique_list

Comment: You cant do: `workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(D:\Research Projects\Research\DEM\DEM.gdb)` instead: `workspace = r'D:\Research Projects\Research\DEM\DEM.gdb'`. You indentation is incorrect in the function and it is not returning anything. `geometries = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(line_layer,arcpy.Geometry())` will create a result object called `geometries` which you then try to use like it is a geometry. You need to execute the code line by line and debug each line.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will work around and will post a more clear and descriptive question. I myself need to spend more time on this. Sorry, for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: You are not causing any inconviniece. Just edit your question and clearify any questions and it will soon be reopened and can be answered. No need to post a new one if you dont want to.

Comment: Sure I will edit this question but how to file a request for reopening?

Comment: To be re-opened your question needs to be improved by editing. Once improved it is reviewed as to whether it is ready to be re-opened. I recommend two things: 1. To present code that is closer to a code snippet than your whole code or copy/pasted from it: 2. To present error messages as formatted text rather than pictures.

Comment: Also, ArcGIS Pro does not support Python AddIns. You seem to be working with a Python Script Tool.

Comment: You seem to have placed a shapefile within a file geodatabase (using the operating system).  This is forbidden. No Esri tool or library will permit a file geodatabase table named "`p_o_start.shp`" (only alphanumeric and underscore are allowed in table names). Shapefile format and file geodatabase are incompatible. Only place shapefiles in directories (but not within those that end with `.gdb`)

Comment: Thanks, @Vince it worked when I changed the output from a geodatabase to a folder.

Comment: @Vince let me know if you think this question warrants re-opening so you can write your comment as an answer. I suspect it may be a duplicate but have not yet looked for one.

Comment: @PolyGeo Yes, I think it's a duplicate, but don't have time to search.